# How can I use SignalR directly in ES6 classes

Tags: ecmascript-6, signalr

I recently ran into an issue trying to call SignalR functions and receive data from SignalR using ES6 classes with the SignalR proxy. Visual Studio was throwing errors with the "myHub.server.function" syntax for mapped methods.

I would like to better "componentize" my code and SignalR is powering my backend comms (no REST on the backend). BTW, I am not using any more than SignalR, ES6 and JQUERY. Please, no responses about Angular et. Al.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not fancy but made it work for classic ASP.NET:

`npm i signalr -S`

`npm i jquery -S`

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
require("signalr");

export default class SignalRservice {

constructor (url){
    var con = $.hubConnection(url);
    this.connection = con.createHubProxy('ChatHub').connection;

    this.connection.start();
    }
}
```

For ASP.NET Core it is just fancy:

`npm i @aspnet/signalr -S`

```
import {HubConnection} from "@aspnet/signalr";

export default class SignalRservice {

constructor (){
    this.connection = new HubConnection('/ChatHub');

    this.connection.start();
    }
}
```